# Adding new HFS+ partition to fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, hfs+

I'm trying to mount at boot a HFS+ core partition in Linux Ubuntu. I followed some other questions here and I came up with this mount command, which seems to properly work, providing read/write access to the partition:

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw,sizelimit=$((935960064*512)) /dev/sda2 mount
```

Now I would like it to be mounted at boot as usual, so I'm trying to add the proper line to /etc/fstab. This is what I wrote:

```
UUID=0e1ad81d-63b6-35cd-93f0-ea8cfbadaefe       /mnt/480GB1     hfsplus force,rw,sizelimit=479582773248 0       0
```

where:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda2
/dev/sda2: UUID="0e1ad81d-63b6-35cd-93f0-ea8cfbadaefe" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="480GB1" PARTUUID="276b2d0a-193a-4325-a1aa-09dd84516b4e"
```

but this is the answer:

```
sudo mount -a
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

dmesg returns:

```
[10292.068918] hfsplus: invalid secondary volume header
[10292.068922] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The mount error message looks suspicious: "bad superblock on **/dev/loop0**". Are you sure the errors are related to the line you added to /etc/fstab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sizelimit is not identical. Could this be the cause?

Comment: Woh! Good catch! Last time I wrote the line I wrote it properly but I copy-pasted a wrong similar number. It works properly now. Don't know why someone downvoted you.

Comment: Well, because there are a lot of people on SE who believe they are "right" and the others should piss off.